# VHDL, using functions in for generate statement

Tags: function, vhdl

VHDL, using functions in for generate statement

I have a component that should be instantiated about 8000 times, I used for-generate statement with the help of some constant values for reducing amount of code, but I had to declare a function for parametrization of component connections.

My function looks like this:

```pascal
    function dim1_calc (
      cmp_index : integer;
      prt_index : integer
      ) return integer is
      variable updw   : integer := 0;
      variable shft_v : integer := 0;
      variable result : integer := 0;
    begin

      if (cmp_index < max_up) then
        updw := 1;
      else
        updw := 2;
      end if;

      case prt_index is
        when 1 =>
          shft_v := cnst_rom(updw)(1) + (i-1);
        when 2 =>
          shft_v := cnst_rom(updw)(2) + (i);
          --
          --
          --
        when 32 =>
          shft_v := cnst_rom(updw)(32) + (i);
        when others =>
          shft_v := 0;
      end case;

      if (updw = 1) then
        if (shft_v = min_up & ((prt_index mod 2) = 0)) then
          result <= max_up;
        elsif (shft_v = max_up & ((prt_index mod 2) = 1)) then
          result <= min_up;
        elsif (shft_v < max_up) then
          result <= shft_v;
        else
          result <= shft_v - max_up;
        end if;
      else
        --something like first condition statements...
        --
        --
      end if;


      return result;

    end function;
```

and part of my code that uses this function plus some related part looks like this:

```pascal
    --these type definitions are in my package
      type     nx_bits_at is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector (bits-1 downto 0);
      type     mxn_bits_at is array (natural range <>) of nx_bits_at;
    --
    --
    --
      component pn_cmpn is
        port(
          clk      : in  std_logic;
          bn_to_pn : in  nx_bits_at(1 to row_wght);
          pn_to_bn : out nx_bits_at(1 to row_wght)
          );
      end component;
      --
      --
      --
      signal v2c : mxn_bits_at(1 to bn_num)(1 to col_wght);
      signal c2v : mxn_bits_at(1 to pn_num)(1 to row_wght);
      --
      --
      --
      gen_pn : for i in (1 to pn_num) generate

        ins_pn : pn_cmpn port map (
        clk          => clk,
        bn_to_pn(1)  => b2p (dim1_calc(i, 1)) (dim2_calc(i, 1)),
        bn_to_pn(2)  => b2p (dim1_calc(i, 2)) (dim2_calc(i, 2)),
        .
        .
        .
        bn_to_pn(32) => b2p (dim1_calc(i, 32)) (dim2_calc(i, 32)),
        pn_to_bn     => p2b (i)
        );

      end generate;
```

I know that using too many sequential statements together is not appropriate in general, and I'm avoiding them as much as possible, but in this case I assumed that this function won't synthesize into some real hardware, and synthesizer just calculates the output value and will put it in corresponding instantiations of that component. Am I right? or this way of coding leads to extra hardware compared to just 8000 instantiations.

PS1: Initially I used "0 to..." for defining ranges of the 2nd and 3rd dimension of my arrays, but because of confusion that were made in dimension calculation function based on for-generate statement parameter, I replaced them with "1 to...". Is that an OK! coding style or should I avoid it?

PS2: Is there a way that port mapping part in above code combines into something like this:
    (I know this is strongly wrong, it's just a clarification of what I want)

```js
      gen_pn : for i in (1 to pn_num) generate

        ins_pn : pn_cmpn port map (
        clk          => clk,

        gen_bn_to_pn : for j in (1 to 32) generate
            bn_to_pn(j)  => b2p (dim1_calc(i, j)) (dim2_calc(i, j)),
        end generate;

        pn_to_bn     => p2b (i)
        );

      end generate;
```

Let me give another example
Assume that I have a component instantiation like this:

```
    ins_test : test_comp port map (
        clk          => clk,
        test_port(1)  => test_sig(2)
        test_port(2)  => test_sig(3)
        test_port(3)  => test_sig(4)
        );
```

Is there a way that I can use for generate here? something like:

```
    ins_test : test_comp port map (
        clk          => clk,
        gen_pn : for i in (1 to 3) generate
            test_port(i)  => test_sig(i+1)
        end generate;
        );
```

PS3: Is it possible to call a function inside another function in VHDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are usable this way. If you encounter problems, I am sure they will regard details in the design or design tools, rather than the basic approach.

One potential issue is that the function refers to some external "things" such as `max_up, i, cnst_rom` whose declarations are not part of the function nor parameters to it. This makes it an "impure function" which - because it refers to external state or even modifies it - has restrictions on calling it (because the external state may change, results may depend on order of evaluation etc).

If you can make it pure, do so. I have a feeling that `max_up, cnst_rom` are constants : if they aren't used elsewhere, declare them local to the function. And `i` probably ought to be a parameter.

If this is not possible, make the external declarations constants, and preferably wrap them and the function together in a package.

This will just generate the values you need in a small, comprehensible, maintainable form, and not an infinite volume of hardware. I have used  a complex nest of functions performing floating point arithmetic then fiddly range reduction and integer rounding to initialise a lookup table, so fundamentally the approach does work.

Potential pitfall:

Some design tools have trouble with perfectly valid VHDL, if its use is slightly unorthodox. Synplicity cannot synthesise some forms of function (which DO generate hardware) though has no trouble with the equivalent procedure returning the result through an OUT parameter!. XST is considerably better.

XST parsing my lookup table init has an absurd slowdown, quadratic in the number of function calls. But only if you are using the old VHDL parser (the default for Spartan-3). Spartan-6 uses the new parser and works fine ( under a second instead of half an hour!) as do Modelsim and Isim. (haven't tried Synplicity on that project)

Some tools object to unorthodox things in port maps : you may get away with function calls there; or you may have to workaround tool bugs by initialising constants with the calls, and using those constants in the port maps.

And your supplementary questions:

PS1) The correct coding style for an array range is ... whatever makes your intent clear. 
If you find yourself mentally offsetting  by 1 and getting confused or even making errors, STOP! and improve the design.

Some good array indexing styles:

```
type colour is (red, green, blue);
subtype brightness is natural range 0 to 255;

hue : array (colour) of brightness;
gamma : array (brightness) of brightness;
-- here 0 is a legitimate value
channel : array (1 to 99) of frequency;
```

PS2) I think you're asking if you can nest generate statements. Yes.

Details may be awkward and difficult, but yes.

PS3) Yes of course! You can even declare functions local to others; eliminating the possibility they will be accidentally called somewhere they make no sense. They (impure functions) can access the execution scope of the outer function (or process), simplifying parameter lists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Your feeling about max_up, cnst_rom and i was right, and I will make my function pure.
My synthesizer is XST, and my FPGA is virtex-5, so it will be fine then.
About array indexing styles: Thanks, that was a relief :)
And yes I was asking about nested generate statements. But this a special case and apparently I didn't explain it well. I added another example for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
Q1 - in this case I assumed that this function won't synthesize into some ...
```

It depends on which synthesizer you're using. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10558259/2778477) relevant question and comments below.

---

```
Q2 - PS1: Initially I used "0 to..." for defining ranges of the ...
```

Surely it's OK.  And please allow we to post a suggestion on coding style here. (from [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0792384741))
***When defining the loop parameter specification, either use a type (or subtype) definition, or use predefined object attributes (e.g., PredefinedObject'range, PredefinedObject'length - 1 downto 0). Avoid using discrete range (e.g., 1 to 4).***
***This rule makes the code more reusable and flexible for maintenance.***

---

```
Q3 - PS2: Is there a way that port mapping part in above code combines into ...
```

I think this is why you asked the 4th question. So refer to the next answer:).

---

```
Q4 - Is it possible to call a function inside another function in VHDL?
```

Though I can't find some official reference to this, the answer is yes.

PS: Coding rules are defined by the synthesizer tools. So the best way to find an answer is to try it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and references of course.
My synthesizer is XST so fortunately there won't be a problem.
I didn't know that my last two questions were connected! so please let me know how can I use functions for my purpose.
And about your PS: I will keep it in mind and will do it more frequently.